# Visa/biometric appointment query for parents

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I have applied for standard visa for my parents. Completed and submitted both of the applications.
Now I want to book the biometric appointment together. How do I make sure they get the appointment together?

I was able to book it for my father on 23rd September but when I am trying to book for my mothers application I can’t see the option to select the date. By default a date is getting selected which is 21st September. There is no option coming to change the date even though the slots are available. I don’t want this. I want both of these applications to go together because my mother is dependent on my father so I don’t want her application to get rejected.

Do they allow husband and wife together even if I have booked the bio-metric appointment for my father only because he is the primary applicant and my mother is his dependent and they will need to be travelling together?
Please any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Maybe try again tomorrow?

Comment: @HankyPanky I already tried multiple times on multiple days with multiple browsers but no success.

Comment: What if i cancel and create another application? Will i get full refund for cancellation?